# How to import module from the parent directory of my parent folder?

Tags: python, python-import

Presently I have a directory structure like :

```
A
  myscript.py
B
C
 D
  module.py
```

I want to import `module` into my script, what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add an empty `__init__.py` to `C` and `D`, and then:

```
import C.D.module
```

Comment: Provided there are \_\_init\_\_.py in the subdirs.

Comment: i was using pycharm IDE that time and it is still working fine there, but when i try to run the script from python console it shows me same import error.

Comment: Are you using the samepython version in both?